# How to update expired Skype signing key

Tags: linux-mint, apt, gpg, skype

Yesterday, I received signature expired:

```
Err:24 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                             
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
```

Today the same problem, solutions?

I'm on Linux Mint 20.1.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple, Microsoft keeps their updated GPG signing key in this file: https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY

So, one can do for example:

```
curl -s https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

---

Note: You should not implicitly trust any key (or file for that matter) and inspect the file thoroughly, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/653354/126755) for more info. Credit: [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt).

---

### UPDATE

You should see and go about with [this answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735876/126755) instead of this simple one.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to use the following command if you have [Linux Mint Vera (21.1)](https://linuxmint.com/download_all.php) and above:

```
wget -qO- https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY  | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/skype.asc
```

Comment: I should update my answer... Nevertheless, your answer is wrong. The correct procedure is to dearmor the asc file, save it as gpg file first, second to place it to `/usr/share/keyrings/skypeforlinux.gpg`, and finally edit the apt list file so that it contains: `deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/skypeforlinux.gpg] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main`

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend if I didn’t use the command from above on my Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria.

Comment: I think this answer works correctly. Tested on Ubuntu Linux 22.04 on 2023.10.16 successfully.