# repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION

Tags: gpg, skype, apt-key

The following warning message appears during my `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` procedure on Linux Mint 21:

> ```
> W: https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
> ```

I searched through the Microsoft Skype download section mentioning absolutely nothing about their keys or how to manage them.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without this being finally resolved by Microsoft, let this answer serve only as a workaround.

---

Maybe these commands could be chained or something, anyway... my procedure was:

1. Exporting the public key from the now-considered deprecated keyring:

   ```
   apt-key export "D404 0146 BE39 7250 9FD5  7FC7 1F30 45A5 DF75 87C3" > skypeforlinux.asc
   ```
2. De-armoring the file:

   ```
   gpg --dearmor < skypeforlinux.asc > skypeforlinux.gpg
   ```
3. Moving the GPG key file in proper place:

   ```
   sudo mv skypeforlinux.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
   ```
4. Editing my `skype-stable.list`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
   ```

   as follows:

   ```
   deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/skypeforlinux.gpg] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
   ```
5. To prevent changing this file from further updates, setting it immutable:

   ```
   sudo chattr +i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
   ```
6. Finally, removing the GPG file from the original keyring:

   ```
   sudo apt-key del "D404 0146 BE39 7250 9FD5  7FC7 1F30 45A5 DF75 87C3"
   ```

---

Final thoughts, as was said this is merely a workaround of a non-urgent issue, and for sure will have to be fixed by Microsoft itself in the future... And if you can do better than me, feel free to edit this answer directly. Cheers.

Comment: Step #5 is important to don't have this problem in the future!